# awk one single line

Tags: awk

I am trying to use an awk script that compiles several lines into one; how can I do that?

I'm using the command:

```
awk < $pot/towhee.prod 'NR==411{print$5,$6}''NR==412{print$5,$6}''NR==430{print$7,$8}'
```

and it produces this:

```
0.24975E-01 0.00000E+00
0.36574E+04 0.59343E+02
-3340.691 0.399
```

but I want this:

```
0.24975E-01 0.00000E+00 0.36574E+04 0.59343E+02 -3340.691 0.399
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can pipe the output to `paste -sd ' ' -` (note that you can do `NR == 411 || NR == 412 {print $5, $6}`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the *output record separator* to a space (or tab). If you want the output to be printed with a terminating newline, you can change it back before the final print

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} NR==411{print$5,$6}''NR==412{print$5,$6}''NR==430{ORS="\n"; print$7,$8}'
```

Answer (score 3):

[`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html#Printf) allows you more control over the print format, including no new line unless you specify one with a `\n`.

```
awk < $pot/towhee.prod 'NR==411{printf("%s %s ",$5,$6)}''NR==412{printf("%s %s ",$5,$6)}''NR==430{printf("%s %s ",$7,$8)}'
```

`%s`  denotes the string format of the variable. [Other control letters are available](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html#Control-Letters) that allow you more control over the formatting of each variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk < $pot/towhee.prod 'NR==411{print$5,$6}''NR==412{print$5,$6}''NR==430{print$7,$8}' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Thanks! i try this and it work to: 

awk < L040/towhee.prod 'NR==411{printf "%s"" ",$5 " " $6}''NR==412{printf "%s" " ", $5 "  "$6}''NR==430{print $7 " " $8}'